# ordering VirtualHosts in Apache conf

Tags: apache

I'm having issues with my apache configuration.  The expected outcome is to allow all traffic to go to the default site trekfederation.com, UNLESS the subdomain is specified and matched otherwise.  My problem is that some of my subdomains still default to the main site.

I have two files as part of my configuration:

```
 httpd.conf
 ships.conf
```

here's httpd.conf's portion for virtualhost:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier 
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName weather.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias weather.trekfederation.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/weather"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName oldsite.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias oldstore.trekfederation.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/trekfed"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName promenade.trekfederation.com
    Redirect / http://trekfederation.com/shop
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName donations.trekfederation.com
    Redirect / http://trekfederation.com/product-category/donations/
</VirtualHost>

Include conf.d/ships.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias trekfederation.com www.trekfederation.com

Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin"
<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    ServerAlias www.iftcommand.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/trekweb"


</VirtualHost>




# Include conf.d/personal.conf


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ccc.trekfederation.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/ccc"
</VirtualHost>
```

Ships.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ussgeorgewashington.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias ussgeorgewashington.trekfederation.net
    ServerAlias nfc1773a.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias nfc1773a.trekfederation.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/NOVA/USS_GEORGE_WASHINGTON
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ussfarragut.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias ussfarragut.trekfederation.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/NOVA/USS_FARRAGUT
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ussvortex.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias ussvortex.trekfederation.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/NOVA/USS_VORTEX
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ussvictory.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias ussvictory.trekfederation.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/NOVA/USS_VICTORY
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ussnavigator.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias ussnavigator.trekfederation.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/NOVA/USS_NAVIGATOR
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ussfirelace.trekfederation.com
    ServerAlias ussfirelace.trekfederation.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/NOVA/USS_FIRELACE
</VirtualHost>
```

the site i'm working on is ussfirelace.trekfederation.com.  it still routes to trekfederation.com.

it does register with apache -S:

```
     port 80 namevhost ussfirelace.trekfederation.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ships.conf:34)
             alias ussfirelace.trekfederation.net
```

what am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The configs look good to me. Possible solutions / problems:

a) Did you restart your apache to load the new virtual host?

b) Have you checked that the DNS record points as A Record (or CNAME) to your server and no redirect is configured with your NS provider?

c) Have you checked your code, that it does not trigger a redirect (e.g. 301, or javascript...)?

d) Clearing browser cache is also some thing that you should take care of.

e) Doublecheck the URL you type for typos.

Comment: b) and c) are probably irrelevant, you would see the URL change in the browser but the rest are good points. I would add: check the name of the included file and its permissions, it has to be readable by the apache user.
I would also recommend to use the internal vhost management. Most distros provide a `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` type of structure, then it's just a matter of using the appropriate command to enable the ones you want, and each vhost has its own separate conf file.